# about {packet, PacketType} in erlang sockets

Tags: ssl, erlang

I'm currently dealing with a SSL socket. I set it as:

```
{ok, LSocket} = ssl:listen(443, [{packet, http},
                         {reuseaddr, true},
                         {active, false},
                         {certfile, "mycert.pem"},
                         {keyfile, "mykey.pem"}]).
```

but when i pass the socket to another process, which should handle the connection, by calling:

```
ssl:getopts(LSocket, [packet]).
```

i got:

```
{ok,[{packet,0}]}
```

instead of:

```
{ok,[{packet,http}]
```

doesn't 0 mean "raw packet?" and why does this happen?

Comment: This code returns {ok,[{packet,http}]} for me with R14B04

Comment: What version of Erlang are you running?

Comment: Erlang version is R15B. The interesting thing is that the first request is treated as a http_request, while the others come as binaries...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you compiled Erlang yourself? Probably you have messed something up with crypto module.
Try using precompiled 15B02 from Erlang Solutions: https://www.erlang-solutions.com/downloads/download-erlang-otp

The code you demonstrated works fine there with passing to another process:

```
Erlang R15B02 (erts-5.9.2) [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:0] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V5.9.2  (abort with ^G)
1> {ok, LSocket} = ssl:listen(9443, [{packet, http}, {reuseaddr, true}, {active, false}, {certfile, "priv/ssl/ssl.crt"}, {keyfile, "priv/ssl/ssl.key"}]).
{ok,{sslsocket,new_ssl,
               {#Port<0.719>,
                {config,{ssl_options,[],verify_none,
                                     {#Fun<ssl.1.38762831>,[]},
                                     false,false,undefined,1,<<"priv/ssl/ssl.crt">>,undefined,
                                     <<"priv/ssl/ssl.key">>,undefined,[],undefined,<<>>,
                                     undefined,undefined,
                                     [<<0,...>>,<<...>>|...],
                                     #Fun<ssl.0.38762831>,true,...},
                        [{packet,http},{reuseaddr,true},{active,false}],
                        {socket_options,list,http,0,0,false},
                        [{reuseaddr,true},
                         {packet_size,0},
                         {packet,0},
                         {header,0},
                         {active,false},
                         {mode,binary}],
                        {gen_tcp,tcp,tcp_closed,tcp_error}}}}}
2> 
2> ssl:getopts(LSocket, [packet]).
{ok,[{packet,http}]}
3> spawn(fun() -> ssl:getopts(LSocket, [packet]) end).
<0.42.0>
4> spawn(fun() -> error_logger:info_msg(ssl:getopts(LSocket, [packet])) end).
<0.44.0>
5> 
=INFO REPORT==== 1-Nov-2012::06:07:15 ===
ERROR: {ok,[{packet,http}]} - []
```